# Setting Up Server in PHP and Android to get push notification with the new json-services JSON

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to use Google Cloud Messaging to send push-notifications from my web server whenever something is triggered from the server (PHP). As I read the Google Cloud Messaging just lately has the google-services.json which needed to be moved to the app/ in the Android project. Now, from the tutorial I've tried to look none are using the google-services.json yet. The documentation is pretty explanatory but I still haven't got the clear mind of setting PHP server to send from the server not the Android java program..

Would there be any link or reference related to the topic I asked? 
Should I follow the tutorials out there without using the lastest API or what should I'd be recommended do?

Thank you, any help would really be appreciated as I also continue to find out.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the official GCM demo for the client side. For the server side, you could do your curl calls, taking into account the required headers and properties. If you look at the Java program that acts as a sender, it simply makes HTTP requests.

Older tutorials will unfortunately have differences, such as the URL to send to and the JSON content.